# Перенаправление с учетом параметров

Tags: роутинг, .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как перенаправить с

```
http://site.ru/name/name2
```

на

```
http://site.ru/index.php?par1=name&par2=name2
```

чтобы можно было вместо name и name2 вставить любой текст?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Модуль Apache mod_rewrite](http://www.egoroff.spb.ru/portfolio/apache/mod_rewrite.html)

[Руководство по URL преобразованиям](http://www.egoroff.spb.ru/portfolio/apache/rewriteguide.html)

P.S.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?par1=$1&par2=$2
```

P.P.S. Печально... Да ещё и роутинг какой-то...

Comment: @klopp, А можно как-то сделать так, чтобы в место name и name2 можно было написать любые слова?

Comment: Sorry, сразу поправил пример, сначала описался. А вообще - ссылки на документацию даны, там всё прекрасно расписано.